# Assigning Variables from csv file

Tags: vbscript

I have a csv file (sample)

```
Firm,Code,Server
Adsuar,BZ,RKASP01
Ahlers,AU,RKASP02
Andrews,CW,RKASP02
Armbrecht,AS,RKASP02
Barron,ZZ,RKASP01
Beckman,BI,RKASP02
```

and am trying to find a way in vbscript to have a single select box on my website that lists the values of column A, and then populate two variables with the contents of column B and C in the same row.

I have what I need to read the csv file and can loop through the file and echo all the contents, however I'm having some trouble finding where to go from here. Any suggestions on where I can start would be appreciated.

The code I have currently is

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\rkaspctl01\n$\wwwroot\dev\clients.csv", 1)

do while not (objTextFile.AtEndOfStream)
  arrStr = Split(objTextFile.ReadLine, ",")
  strFirm = arrStr(0)
  strCode = arrStr(1)
  strServer = arrStr(2)
Loop

objTextFile.close
```

Thanks 
Patrick Stoddard

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual question is. Your code sample does read records from the CSV file. What do you want to do with the data once you read it from the file?

Answer (score 0):

Start putting your data in a key/value pair (dictionary) where the key is the value from column A, the value is an array containing the values from column B and C:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\rkaspctl01\n$\wwwroot\dev\clients.csv", 1)
Set objFirmDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

do while not (objTextFile.AtEndOfStream)
  arrStr = Split(objTextFile.ReadLine, ",")
  objFirmDict.Add arrStr(0), array(arrStr(1), arrStr(2))
Loop

objTextFile.close
```

Now you can populate your listbox with the keys from the dictionary.
Pseudocode:

```
firmListbox = document.getElementById("firmSelect")
For each firm in objFirmDict.Keys
    Set newOption = document.createElement("option")
    newOption.text = firm
    newOption.value = firm
    firmListbox.Add newOption, Nothing
Next
```

When an option is selected, update the two variables with the correct text.

On you webpage:

```
<input type="select" id="firmSelect" onchange="vbscript:firmSelectChange me.Value">
```

The onchange event calls the firmSelectChange sub. This has to retrieve the two variables from the dictionary. Please note: The dictionary must have a global scope for the document.

Pseudocode for this handling sub:

```
Sub firmSelectChange(value)
    dataArr = objFirmDict.Item(value)
    code = dataArr(0)
    server = dataArr(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TDC ([Tabular Data Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>TDC Example</TITLE>

<OBJECT ID="dataTDC" CLASSID="CLSID:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83">
  <PARAM NAME="TextQualifier" VALUE="">
  <PARAM NAME="FieldDelim" VALUE=",">
  <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="data.csv">
  <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" VALUE="true">
</OBJECT>

</HEAD>
<BODY>

<TABLE DATASRC="#dataTDC" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
  <THEAD>
    <TR>
      <TD><B>Firm</B></TD>
      <TD><B>Code</B></TD>
      <TD><B>Server</B></TD>
    </TR>
  </THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="Firm"></SPAN></TD>
    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="Code"></SPAN></TD>
    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="Server"></SPAN></TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Output result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you AutomatedChaos and Panayot both options have given me a good starting point. I will see what I can do with them and let you know what happens.